# React native: Update value of object in array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I have a component which changes the state when checkbox is checked and the data needs to be updated of the object in the array.

The component state looks something like this
{
key:1,
todo:"Something",
isChecked:false
}

i have 3 files:
AddTodo.js Which passes state & setState to an component TodoList which passes it the subcomponent TodoItem.

I am unable to update the state from TodoItem , I need to implement a function that finds the object from array and updates its isChecked state.

AddTodo.js

```
function AddTodo() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [todos, addTodos] = useState([]);
  var keys = (todos || []).length;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={state}
        statusBarTranslucent={true}
      >
        <View style={styles.itemsContainer}>
          <GetInfoDialog
            state={state}
            stateChange={setState}
            addItem={addTodos}
            numKeys={keys}
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
      {(todos || []).length > 0 ? (
        <TodoList data={todos} updateState={addTodos} />
      ) : null}
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.btn}
        onPress={() => {
          setState(true);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>Add New</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

TodoList.js

```
function TodoList(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.todoList}>
      <FlatList
        data={props.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          console.log(item);
          return (
            <TodoItem
              list={props.data}
              itemKey={item.key}
              todo={item.todo}
              isChecked={item.isChecked}
              updateState={props.updateState}
            />
          );
        }}
        backgroundColor={"#000000"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

TodoItem.js

```
function TodoItem(props) {
  const [checked, setCheck] = useState(props.isChecked);

  return (
    <View style={styles.todoItem}>
      <Checkbox
        value={checked}
        onValueChange={() => {
          setCheck(!checked);
        }}
        style={styles.checkbox}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{props.todo}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: The current code is incomplete. Please add the `TodoList`. Furthermore, you are not updating any state in `TodoItem` other than its internal state. You never use a function passed via props.

Comment: I have updated the question please check, also i was trying to implement a function that updates the state of todos but it was giving some errors.

Comment: You are never using `updateState` in `TodoItem`. How should the parent state be updated then?

Comment: Your current code segment doesn't update any state. Please share your TodoList as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          console.log(item);
          return (
            <TodoItem
              list={props.data}
              itemKey={item.key}
              todo={item.todo}
              isChecked={item.isChecked}
              updateState={props.updateState}
              setChecked={(value)=>{
                let updatedList = [...yourTodosList]
                updatedlist[index].isChecked=value
                setTodos(updatedList)
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
```

and in your todo item

```
onValueChange={(value) => {
     props.setChecked(value);
}}
```

i also don't think that you need an is checked state in your todo component since you are passing that through props (so delete `const [checked, setCheck] = useState(props.isChecked)` line and just use the value you are getting from props.isChecked)

didn't pay much attention to your variable names but this should put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

as per [React Native Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) you have to call

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCheck(checked);
}, [checked]) // now this listens to changes in contact
```

in TodoItem.tsx

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed to call `setCheck` inside `onValueChange`? This will also create an infinite loop, since `setCheck` is called in an effect which contains the same state that will be set in its dependency array.